# Server-side of a chat application

Tags: java, multithreading, socket, chat

I have written a server-side and the client-side of a chat application. I would like to improve it and I am unsure about my server construct and have absolutely no idea if there is a better way to do it. I haven't found anything on Google, therefor I ask you. The construct I have used is from a tutorial from Oracle I found through Google, but I can't find the link now.

My code works like this:

I have a server waiting for clients to connect to this server. If a client wants to connect to the server, the server assigns a `ClientConnector` to the client. This `ClientConnector` is pulling the messages from the client. These messages will be stored in two `ArrayList`s. One is there, if we shut down the server, that it is saving these messages. The other `ArrayList` is for my class `MessageReader`, which just prints the messages to the console of the server. It will later forward them to all other clients.

My "problem"/question:

I don't know exactly why I need it and it took me about 2 days to find out. That it is necessary but in my class `MessageReader`, it won't print out messages unless there is a `Thread.sleep`.

**Server:**

```
package TwoWayCommunicationVersion04.Server;

import TwoWayCommunicationVersion04.Client.Client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/******************************************************************************
 *
 * Server
 * clientConnectors - Place to store the clients who are connected to the
 *                    server.
 * clientMessages   - Place to temporally store the messages from the
 *                    clients, automatically emptying the ArrayList, when
 *                    the message is handled by the server
 *
 ****************************************************************************/
public class Server extends Thread {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private ArrayList<ClientConector> clientConectors = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<String> clientMessagesBackup= new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> clientMessages = new ArrayList<>();


    /**************************************************************************
     * Server-Constructor
     * @param port the port the server listens to
     **************************************************************************/
    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * getClientMessageList
     * @return the destination for the clientMessages
     **************************************************************************/
    public ArrayList<String> getClientMessageList() {
        return clientMessages;
    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * listenSockets
     * @param socket ususally serverSocket.accept()
     *
     * task -------- accepting the new Client
     **************************************************************************/
    private void listenSockets(Socket socket) {
        System.out.println("GOT CLIENT");
        ClientConector clientConector = new ClientConector(socket, clientMessages, clientMessagesBackup);
        clientConectors.add(clientConector);
        clientConector.start();
    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * closeServer
     * Saving the collected data to some files and then closing the sockets
     **************************************************************************/
    private void closeServer() throws IOException {
        serverSocket.close();

        /**
         * Going to add that the messages and so on will be safed
         */

    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * startServer
     * If there are some files that the server can use then this mehtod will
     * analyze them first and then use them. These files contain e.g. the
     * Client-ID's of the Clients who connected to the server.
     **************************************************************************/
    private void startServer() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            System.out.println("STARTED SERVER");
            while (true) {
                listenSockets(serverSocket.accept());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`ClientConnector`:**

```
package TwoWayCommunicationVersion04.Server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 *
 */
public class ClientConector extends Thread {

    private static Socket socket;

    private ArrayList<String> clientMessages;
    private ArrayList<String> clientMessagesBackup;

    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;



    public ClientConector(Socket socket, ArrayList<String> clientMessages, ArrayList<String> clientMessagesBackup){
        this.socket = socket;
        initStreams();
        setArrayLists(clientMessages, clientMessagesBackup);
    }

    private void setArrayLists(ArrayList<String> clientMessages, ArrayList<String> clientMessagesBackup){
        this.clientMessages = clientMessages;
        this.clientMessagesBackup = clientMessagesBackup;
    }

    private void initStreams() {
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("FAILED TO INITIALIZE STREAMS");
        }
    }

    private void closeClient() {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("FAILED TO CLOSE SOCKETS AND/OR STREAMS");
        }
    }

    private void pullMessages() throws IOException {
        String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if(message != null) {
            System.out.println("GOT MESSAGE" +
                    "\n\t\tARRAYLIST-SIZE: " + clientMessages.size() +
                    "\n\t\tARRAYLIST-SIZE (BACKUP) : " + clientMessagesBackup.size());
            clientMessages.add(message);
            clientMessagesBackup.add(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    System.out.println("STARTED DEALING WITH CLIENT");
        try {
            while(true){
                pullMessages();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**`MessageReader`:**

```
package TwoWayCommunicationVersion04.Server;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by zeljko on 22.12.15.
 */
public class MessageReader extends Thread{

    private ArrayList<String> clientMessages;

    public MessageReader(ArrayList<String> clientMessages){
        this.clientMessages = clientMessages;
    }

    private void readMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        while(!clientMessages.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(clientMessages.get(0));
            clientMessages.remove(0);
        }
        //Without this he will not print out the messages
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                readMessage();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to take a look on the rest of the stuff, [here is my GitHub](https://github.com/SparkMonkay/00_Server/tree/9068bcd941ee2e0a5ce8984f4db0921acca1959b) link to the repository. There is my client, and "older" versions of the server and client.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` may not be available from the additional thread. Unpredictable behavior results from this type of access stdout, network connections, files, hardware resources. To capture the output, instead use a concurrent logger which can receive output from multiple threads into a thread safe collection, retrieving and appending those messages to a file. There are `logj4` and others or you can [roll your own](https://catjcode.com/websvn/listing.php?repname=logging&path=%2Flogging%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fcatjcode%2F&#a7aa3b404f3786d2d25fba02cb4771a74).

Comment: I though, that if I throw all my input in one central "thing", here an ArrayList, it would work without problems. I have also used some `System.out` so I don't think that it isn't available.